Query returning zero observations although it should
I'm writing a query for work, and I know what I'm looking for exists in the table, but it's returning zero observations. I'm assuming it is because of the importation process, but I checked the column attributes and they are formatted the same. Here's what it looks like
/* file importation containing diagnosis codes */
proc import datafile = "&file."
out = file_name
dbms = xlsx replace;
getnames = yes;
sheet = sheet_name;
run;

/* pull all data with the diagnosis code listed on the claim */
proc sql;
create table data_table1
as select distinct *
from main_table
where diagnosis in (select distinct diagnosis_code from file_name)
quit;

When doing this I get zero observations. When I manually input a diagnosis code it pulls, but there are just too many to do all of them. Any idea why it is not pulling?

create table data_table1 as just creates a new table, it won't return any data. Not clear why you need a new table anyway.

Which dbms are you using? What are you trying to do?
